# how to map one to many mapping within the same table in Hibernate

Tags: java, hibernate, orm, hibernate-mapping

I have a table like this:

```
Id int
Source VARCHAR
Target VARCHAR
```

And I want to query like this:

```
select * from `TestTable` t1
left join `TestTable` t2 on t1.`Target` = t2.`Target`
and t1.`Id` <> t2.`Id`
```

So how to code the mapping with java annotation?

And how to query with hibernate?

Comment: What have you tried so far? Can you try mapping two relationships namely one to many and many to one in your Target class it self and can you try writing an HQL and see what happens?

Comment: Take a look at this self join example. I am assuming that the only thing that will change in your case is the query. http://viralpatel.net/blogs/hibernate-self-join-annotations-one-to-many-mapping/

Answer (score 0):

Mapping One to Many in hibernate with the same table is not a problem you can do with annotations like this:

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "test1")
public class Test1 implements Serializable {

private int id;
private String source;
private String target;

private List<Test1> others;

@Id
public int getId() {
    return id;
}

public void setId(int id) {
    this.id = id;
}

@Column(name = "source")
public String getSource() {
    return source;
}

public void setSource(String source) {
    this.source = source;
}

@Column(name = "target")
public String getTarget() {
    return target;
}

public void setTarget(String target) {
    this.target = target;
}

@OneToMany(targetEntity = Test1.class)
public List<Test1> getOthers() {
    return others;
}

public void setOthers(List<Test1> others) {
    this.others = others;
}

}
```

The problem is the type of your relation because the relations not seems to be with the primary key. Then the relation is not strict "OneToMany". With the query like you write you can change the referencedColumnName in the JoinColumn annotation like this:

```
    @JoinColumn(name = "target", referencedColumnName = "target")
```

But with this mapping, if the parent object has the same "target" field then the parent object is included as child because you cannot put the other part of the query in the mapping

```
t1.`Id` <> t2.`Id`
```